# if I click on external link, it counts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I do the following thing:

> When a user clicks on an external link e.g http://google.pl, jQuery detects the click and do some action.

I can do this using PHP, but then the link will be not external.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: To handle click events with jQuery you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), but your question is pretty vague, you need to add more info about it.

Comment: please show us the markup of both internal and external linlks

Comment: Do you only want to check how many clicks you have on a link, or do you want to present them for the user aswell?

Comment: i want present them for the user (ajax)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to process every link click:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    ... do something ...
});
```

or you may filter links using something like:

```
$('a[href^="http://google.com/"]')
```

Comment: This would be the first step, then do a $.post() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ to your php server side, wich will save the click in a DB, then do a callback in your success function to update the DOM.

Comment: Why to do that? There is nothing about that in the question. Maybe he wants to do something in client side. Strange question, really.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!

```html
$('a.externallink').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({  
              url: "/count.php?id="+id
             });
});
```